# wagtail <ul class='chooser__action'> ... </ul> causing list not to be displayed

Tags: wagtail

wagtail `<ul class='chooser__action'> ... </ul>` causing list not to be displayed

we have in our model

```
MultiFieldPanel(
            heading='Hero',
            classname='collapsible',
            children=[
                FieldPanel('hero_image'),
                MediaChooserPanel('hero_video'),
                FieldPanel('mobile_hero_image'),
                FieldPanel('hero_title'),
                FieldPanel('hero_strapline'),
                FieldPanel('hero_cta_text'),
                FieldPanel('hero_cta_link'),
            ]
        ),
```

Only for hero_image, change and edit image buttons are not being displayed

because of `<ul>` class

hero_image is defined as

```
 hero_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
```

any idea where this. class would be coming from, fairly new to wagtail

removed class= and edit and change image buttons appear,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chooser__action` class is [part of the HTML common to all chooser widgets](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f1560625aa0dacd11bff010a641170d20258f4d4/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/widgets/chooser.html#L23), and has been that way since Wagtail 4.0. The [CSS rule for this element](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/client/scss/components/_chooser.scss#L71-L92) specifies that the buttons are initially hidden, but revealed when you hover over the chooser element's container (which will be a `<div class="w-field--admin_image_chooser">` element in the case of an image chooser).

Removing the `chooser__action` classname would fix the immediate problem by ensuring that the buttons never get hidden in the first place, but this isn't the intended design of the chooser widget. If the hover-to-reveal mechanism isn't working on your site, it probably means that you (or a third-party add-on you've installed) have made a customisation that either conflicts with this CSS, or modified the HTML so that the expected container element is missing.

Judging from your panel definition, you have [wagtailmedia](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtailmedia) installed - maybe you need to update this to a newer version with Wagtail 4.x support? (I'm pretty sure this would only affect the MediaChooserPanel, though, not the image chooser.)

Comment: container div does not have that class, other images on the page do have it

Comment: it has a containing div with  class = "field model_choice_field admin_image_chooser "

Comment: It looks a lot like you have [the Wagtail <=3.x version of the template wagtailadmin/shared/field.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/3.0.x/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/shared/field.html) sitting around somewhere. Check your project for a template file matching that path - if there isn't one, it might be a badly-behaved third-party package that hasn't yet been updated for Wagtail 4.

Comment: great yes we had custom field.html, that fixed issue many thanks