# wagtail 4.1.5 overriding _chooser.scss class

Tags: wagtail

How do I override the wagtail scss

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/client/scss/components/_chooser.scss#L71

I want to add a class to .chooser__actions

```
.chooser__actions {
  display: flex;
  gap: theme('spacing.[1.5]');

  .button {
    // Subdued border as there can be a lot of chooser action buttons on a page.
    border-color: theme('colors.border-button-small-outline-default');
  }

  // Hiding for devices capable of hover states only,
  // with opacity only so keyboard focus can move to the first interactive element to reveal it.
  @media (hover: hover) {
    opacity: 0;

    // Ensure the hovering over the comment icon will still show chooser actions.
    // Uses a form-field class as well as widget classes, as all core and custom choosers use different widgets.
    :is(.w-field--model_choice_field, .w-field--admin_task_chooser, .w-field--admin_page_chooser, .w-field--document_chooser_widget, .w-field--admin_image_chooser, .w-field--admin_snippet_chooser):is(:hover, :focus-within)
      & {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

to include another class for the hover in :is

Thanks

to be able to add another class to the hover is:

Comment: Presumably this is a follow-up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230318/wagtail-ul-class-chooser-action-ul-causing-list-not-to-be-displayed ? I wouldn't recommend trying to work around it in this way - the incorrect class names on the container element are a sign of bigger problems in the HTML structure.